# onResume() is not called in physical device instead onCreate() is called

Tags: android

Iam little bit amazed with this.I have an onResume() in my activity.Its called and works well in my emulator, but  in a physical device samsung galaxy note for specific with jellybean installed,its not called.Instead onCreate() is called all the time.Why this happens?

```
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    if(firsttime){
        try {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Resuming Activity",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            addReminder();
        } catch(Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        firsttime=true;
    }
}
```

This is my code.firsttime is a static boolean variable.It is used to prevent onResume() being called when app is started for the first time

Comment: post some code. How do you know it doesn't get called?

Comment: post ur onResume Method fully

Comment: `firsttime` isn't a `static int` but rather a `static boolean`, I suppose.

Comment: Make a toast before the `if(firsttime)` block and see if that one is being called.

Comment: And your boolean is false first Time?

Comment: Check if don't keep activities option is disabled or not in settings developer options

Comment: @PiyushGupta yes it is.And i mentioned that onResume() is working perfectly in emulator.But its not working in my physical device only.

Comment: I think you are doing something extremely wrong.
Can you tell me what are you trying to achieve,
Do you want to execute some code when application is started first time or activity is started first time ?

Comment: I wish to execute some code when the activity resumes.And the onResume() should not be called when activity is started for the first time.

Comment: Where are you changing that member to true value?

Comment: @vilpe89 within the onResume() its in my code and its set to false in onCreate() initially

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering your current scenario, you should save variable in preferences instead of relying on activities lifecycle since lifecycle depends on many things.
Using static variable for this scenario is bad choice in general.I think this should solve your problem.

Comment: yes I have changed my code when its found to be a failure.But I wish to know that why this happens eventhough in the emulator it runs why is it not running in physical device?

Comment: What is happening in emulator is your activity is not getting destroyed due to less load on os and which is leading to preserving static variable,
on the other hand in device,activity is getting destroyed and process is getting killed.Due to which your static variable is garbage collected and next time you open application you get "false" where you were expecting "true"

Answer (score 0):

Try to print something inside the onResume and check it in LogCat.... the code inside onResume may be causing this.
or else can you elaborate your question?

Comment: Code doesn't belong here in the comments, please edit your question instead. `firsttime` isn't a `static int` but rather a `static boolean`

Comment: sorry because iam new to stack overflow.I have edited it and as you said its static boolean in my actual code.

Comment: This `answer` is more of a `comment`, really.

Comment: onResume() is called in the emulator.In the physical device its not working.I have tested it in only one phone.

Answer (score 0):

I think here is what happens, 
when your app not the Top app, the activity manager actually destroy the activity, it only called

```
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

no

```
    onStop
```

called, so no

```
    noResume
```

will be called.

The correct to do this is, when put all states of this activity when

```
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

called.

and in your onCreate() function, do such thing

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); // Always call the superclass first

    // Check whether we're recreating a previously destroyed instance
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        // Restore value of members from saved state
        mCurrentScore = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SCORE);
        mCurrentLevel = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_LEVEL);
    } else {
        // Probably initialize members with default values for a new instance
    }
    ...
}
```

to check if you have some saved state.

Most code was copy from android developer site:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html